# Router Parameter in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

The problem is that router parameters are showing in URL while I want my router parameter not to show in URL ?

myComponent.ts

```
@RouteConfig([      
        { path: '/routerOne/:myId', component: routerOne, name: "routerOne",useAsDefault: true},
        { path: '/routerTwo/:myId', component: routerTwo, name: "routerTwo"},

])
```

myComponent.html

```
  <a [routerLink]="['routerOne',{myId:this.Id}]">RouterOne</a>
  <a [routerLink]="['routerTwo',{myId:this.Id}]">routerTwo</a>
```

Comment: best way to do it is by sharedService as of now, i think !

Comment: could you please explain how to do with shared devices as you said, if you provide example its much better for us.

Answer (score 1):

As of now `sharedService` can be the last option as you don't want to show data in `url`. `RouteData` can be an option but it is `immutable`.
please read this two threads carefully.

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6672

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6569

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send static value via routing as parameters then you can send via `data` property of routing in angular2 by using this parameters does't show in the URL.

Basically There are two options (upto my knowledge) to send data via routing

- *RouteParams*          (as used in question)
- *data(RouteData)*       (property at the time of routing)

## RouteParams

Now when we send data using `RouteParams` we have to define in the similer way like this:

```
{path: '/editUser/:userId', name: 'Edit User', component: UserEditComponent}

<a href="#" [routerLink]="['Edit User',{userId: id}]"
```

By using this method we send data normaly but all data is visible in the URL

## Data

when we don't want to show data in the URL path than we have to send data via routing using `data` property of the `@RouteConfig annotation` provided by angualr2. by using this property we can send additional data to the components at the time of the route configuration without showing it in the URL. here is example of this property.

```
@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/product/:id', component: ProductDetailComponentParam,
     as: 'ProductDetail', data: {isProd: true}}])

export class ProductDetailComponentParam {
    productID: string;
    constructor(params: RouteParams, data: RouteData) {
        this.productID = params.get('id');
 
        console.log('Is this prod environment', data.get('isProd'));
    }
}
```

by using this we can send data via routing without showing in the URL.
[Plunker - working example of the same](http://plnkr.co/edit/N5IzUH0pc3nN1O7iQZkD?p=preview)

for more info read this [awesome artical](https://yakovfain.com/2015/11/11/angular-2-passing-data-to-routes/)