# Angular 2 error: Cannot resolve all parameters for 'RouteParams'

Tags: routes, angular

Trying to use RouteParams to get query-string parameters, but I just get the error

> Cannot resolve all parameters for 'RouteParams'(?). Make sure that all
>   the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type
>   annotations and that 'RouteParams' is decorated with Injectable.
>   angular2-polyfills.js:332 Error: Cannot read property 'getOptional' of
>   undefined.......

Check out this [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/t6wyJDLOFGufQK0XUZZD?p=preview). How can I use RouteParams without getting this warning?

The important files are:

`boot.ts`:

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS, RouteParams} from 'angular2/router';
import {AppComponent} from './app/app.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS, RouteParams]);
```

and `app.component.ts`:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {RouteParams} from "angular2/router";

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `
    <p *ngIf="guid">guid gived is: {{guid}}</p>
    <p *ngIf="!guid">No guid given in query-string in URL</p>
  `
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  guid:string;

  constructor(private _params: RouteParams) {} //

  ngOnInit() {
    this.guid = this._params.get('guid');
  }

}
```

**Update:**

I am not having any routes, I just have the default root route (if that can be called a route at all when I have no other routes...). But as suggested by Gianluca, I added the following route config:

```
@RouteConfig([
  { path: '/:guid', name: 'Home', component: AppComponent, useAsDefault: true },
])
```

But I still get the same error (the [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/t6wyJDLOFGufQK0XUZZD?p=preview) is updated)...

Comment: from where this `guid` coming from ? if you are not having any route ?

Comment: It just a querystring I need for my app, so somebody would use it like this: mydomain.com/myapp?guid=something. Could perhaps have called it something else here, like "testparamenter" or something...

Comment: i just posted my answer hope that'l help you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remove `RouteParams` from

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS, RouteParams]);
```

`RouteParams` is provided by the router. If you provide it yourself injecting it fails.

See https://angular.io/api/router/Params for an example. `RouteParams` can only be injected on components added by the router.

[**Plunker example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/reqRrxi21bYaaXcto39t?p=preview)

Comment: If I do that I get another error: `EXCEPTION: No provider for RouteParams!`

Comment: Can you edit the plunker and make it work? I removed both ROUTER_PROVIDERS, RouteParams from bootstrap (and the import), and added `providers: [RouteParams]` on the component, but getting same error...

Answer (score 3):

After seeing the correct and accepted answer to Günter, I wanted to add an answer of my own (I asked the original question).

This is really overkill for my case: I have no routing (I have only a single page single page application), so I must:

- bring in another "external" component (RouteConfig)
- create a dedicated component with the router config and router base template (with `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`)
- inject RouteParams in the component where I want to use the query string parameter

And then finally I am able to the query string parameter...

In my case (with just one parameter), I just instead did this one-liner (spread over 4 lines for easy reading):

```
this.myParameter = window.location.href
  .slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1)
  .split('&')[0]
  .split('=')[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you specified `guid` in the @RouteConfig?

```
@RouteConfig([
  {path: '/something/:guid', name: 'Something', component: Something}
])
```

Comment: Even if I do not have any routes (except the default root route (is that a route at all when not using the router))? Is there another way of getting the url query params?

Comment: I don't think so... routeParams requires configuration from RouteConfig, like in Angular 1. You can add `useAsDefault: true` option to specify default root route.

Comment: I added @RouteConfig, still get the same error (see the same plunker). I updated question with this too...

Comment: PS :- `as` has been changed to `name` in angular2 beta .

Answer (score 0):

i am not understand you problem correctly but yes as you said in comment

> Is there another way of getting the url query params?

Than we can send via using `data` property 
we can send data via routing using `data` property of the `@RouteConfig annotation` provided by angualr2. by using this property we can send additional data to the components at the time of the route configuration without showing it in the URL. here is example of this property.

```
@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/product/:id', component: ProductDetailComponentParam,
     as: 'ProductDetail', data: {isProd: true}}])

export class ProductDetailComponentParam {
    productID: string;
    constructor(params: RouteParams, data: RouteData) {
        this.productID = params.get('id');

        console.log('Is this prod environment', data.get('isProd'));
    }
}
```

by using this we can send data via routing without showing in the URL.
[Plunker - working example of the same](http://plnkr.co/edit/N5IzUH0pc3nN1O7iQZkD?p=preview)

for more info read this [awesome artical](https://yakovfain.com/2015/11/11/angular-2-passing-data-to-routes/)

see also -

- [Router Parameter in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36052635/5043867)

Comment: I am interested in getting parameters (from the url query string), not setting...

Comment: getting from where i did't get your point sorry. you have only one router than from where you can get params ?