# Angular2: what is difference between resolve and data in routing paths?

Tags: angular, parameters, components, angular2-routing, angular2-router

I see that are 2 ways to pass simple data, such as strings, to different components from routing paths:

**First way:**

Routing side:

```
export const AppRoutes: Routes = [
  ...
  { 
    path: '/one', component: OneComponent, resolve: { foo: 'foo' }
  }
];
```

Component side:

```
@Component()
export class OneComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.foo = this.route.snapshot.data['foo'];
    }
}
```

**Second way:**

Routing side:

```
const routes: RouterConfig = [
    ...
    {
      path: '/one', component: OneComponent, data : {some_data : 'some value'}
    }
];
```

Component side:

```
@Component()
export class OneComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.obs = this.route
          .data
          .subscribe(v => console.log(v));
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.obs.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

So which is the best way to pass values to components? What are the differences between `resolve` and `data` properties?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/36030932/5043867 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/36498736/5043867

Comment: Isn't `RouteParams` deprecated?

Comment: yeah that was deprecated in angular2 beta i think

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`data` is static data added to the route, while resolve calls a service that can calculate data, also using async calls.

Your `resolve` example is invalid.

See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#resolve-guard

Comment: Thank you for your reply! So what is the difference between using `resolve` and invoking `service` from components that need it?